# Disable completionItemProvider inside quotations

Tags: typeahead, monaco-editor

I've successfully used `monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider` to populate a completion list. Is there any way for monaco to detect when the cursor is in-between single or double quotes and temporarily deactivate the completion provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can embed any kind of logic into your `CompletionItemProvider`. You can use the provdied `Position` and parse the file to figure out if you are inside single or double quotes and then return a `[]` accordingly.